# How to set a time limit in a loop (batch file)

Tags: batch-file, timer, cmd

I have a batch code that calls another program (meshlab) in a loop, the average time for one instance is about 6 minutes, some times it takes much more than that (possibly stuck in some complicated calculations). So I would like to know if there is a possibilty where I can set a timer for the loop to go on to the next step. Here is an example of the code:

```
   FOR %%I IN (C:\Users\Salam\Desktop\PreProcessed_Bosphorus\bs!var!\*.ply) DO (
        meshlabserver -i %%~dpnxI -o %%~nI.ply -s C:\Users\Salam\Desktop\PreProcessed_Bosphorus\iso_per.mlx -om vn -l %%~nI.txt
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** This addition will kill any running `meshlabserver.exe` process but it will always wait 600 seconds, even if the previous task only took 3 minutes.

taskkill and timeout are in Windows Vista and later IIRC

This will launch an instance, and wait `600` seconds and then it will iterate through the loop and start another instance.  Did you want to `kill` the running process, or just start another instance of meshlabserver?

```
FOR %%I IN (C:\Users\Salam\Desktop\PreProcessed_Bosphorus\bs!var!\*.ply) DO (
        start "" meshlabserver -i %%~dpnxI -o %%~nI.ply -s C:\Users\Salam\Desktop\PreProcessed_Bosphorus\iso_per.mlx -om vn -l %%~nI.txt
        timeout 600 >nul
        taskkill /f /im meshlabserver.exe >nul 2>&1
    )
```

Comment: It would be better if I can kill the running process, otherwise it will run forever.

Comment: are the quotation marks empty or meant to be around the meshlabserver statement ?

Comment: They are empty.  You can put text in between and it will be the title bar of the program window.  They matter when other quoted terms are in the line and are good practice.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't in batch. `FOR` doesn't have parameters to do that, and you cannot break the call to meshlabserver in another way, because the batch script is disabled as long a meshlabserver is running.

If you would have a programming langugage which supports threading, then you could fire the meshlabserver program in the background, wait for it, and kill the thread (and maybe even the process itself) is it takes too long for your liking.

Comment: You can do that in batch using the `start` command and a timer.